# PHP preg_match doesn't accept line break

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to recieve value from textarea and I need to allow it to accept line breaks.

I have already tried /s and /m flags after the pattern.
Also there are \r\n and \s exceptions.

Nothing of above made it work.

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);


if(!preg_match("/^[\r\n\/a-z A-ZáéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôûÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÃÕÂÊÎÔÛçÇ 0-9 \- \_ \s \. ,]*$/", $description)) {

   header("Location: index.php?error=invalidDescription");
   exit();

}
```

I'm expecting it to accept the line break.

Comment: I wonder what `$description` is...

Comment: Is it `<br>`? If yes, allow `<>`.

Comment: The problem might be that your double quotes interpret all the special characters, while you need them as part of your regex. You probably want to use single quotes. And you might need `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

Comment: I take it back, I ran some tests and I don't think it's the newlines, the quotes or the match function chosen. Please show sample contents of `$description` you would like to have accepted but isn't accepted, otherwise your question is not clear.

Comment: @joanis It's a simple textarea input so it can be any text, for example:

"Some <br>
text <br>
here"

But without the "<br>" part, because users don't type br, they just press enter to type in a new line.

Answer (score 3):

Since `mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes line-breaks, there's no more line-breaks in your string. The character class in your pattern doesn't include the backslash, that's why the pattern fails.

The simplest solution is to apply `mysqli_real_escape_string` after the pattern. I will write it this way:

```
if ( preg_match('~[^\p{Latin}0-9/\s.,_-]~u', $_POST['description']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php?error=invalidDescription");
    exit();
}

$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);
```

But If you prefer to keep your original code, you only have to add `\\\\` in your character class to figure a literal backslash.